# count duplicates value from mysql row using php

Tags: php, sql

I have table called "hello" and have 2 column called "A" and "B", and column "a" contains many duplicates value such as '123' ,143' 123','222' ,'123' so I want to echo value "123" only once time and its count "3" please help me.

Comment: Why don't you use "group by" ?

Comment: Do you want 122 and 143 returned as well, or only 123?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"select a, count(a) as occurance from hello group by a";

// Here we are GROUPING the table on column a so that we can get its unique value, and count(a) as occurance is the occurance count of its unique values and printing the unique value in column a and there count as occurance like:

123     3
145     5
```

Comment: if you give some explanation about your answer that might help to others.

Comment: Explanation added

Answer (score 0):

Do a SELECT with a GROUP BY clause. Let's say A is the column you want to find counts in:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A) AS TOTAL_COUNT 
FROM hello 
GROUP BY A;
```

This will return a result with the A value in the first column, and a count of how many times that value appears in the second

Answer (score 0):

Get it simply i9n this way

```
SELECT A,count(*) as count FROM `hello` GROUP BY A
```